# Deleting contents of xml file in Qt

Tags: qt, xml-parsing

I have a program which writes xml, I used a logic where it creates a blank xml `if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
    {
        QTextStream stream(&file);
        stream<<""<<endl;
    }
    XMLWriter();`

Then i call XMlwriter . But the problem is when I want to make changes and save it for 2nd time, it's not overwriting. it's just adding to the exisiting file hence creating duplicates. is there any where i can delete the enitre xml contents maybe before `stream<<""<<endl;`

Answer (score 1):

To truncate the file, pass the `QIODevice::Truncate` flag into your [`QFile::open()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#open) call:

```
if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Truncate)) {
    // ....
}
```

Alternately, if you are only writing to the file (and not reading from it), you can use the `QIODevice::WriteOnly` flag, [which implies `QIODevice::Truncate`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#OpenModeFlag-enum):

```
if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
    // ....
}
```